# How to cast an Object when we only have the .class files?

Tags: java, reflection, casting

Let's say I have a class file named *ObjectFoo.class* but I don't have access to *ObjectFoo.java* source file, since **the class file is created during runtime**. Is there a way to cast an object in this case ?

At the moment, I'm using this code to cast the object, but in this example I need to have *ObjectFoo.java* in my classpath :

```
Class c = Class.forName("ObjectFoo");
ObjectFoo object = (ObjectFoo) c.newInstance();
```

The goal is to instantiate an object from its class file using Java reflection. 
**I'm looking for a solution using only Java API and no other third-party libraries.**

Thanks in advance for your answer !

Jonathan.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need the source file in your classpath when using the code?

Comment: What's wrong with `new ObjectFoo`?

Comment: Exactly duplicate of below post http://stackoverflow.com/q/10527658/668970

Comment: @developer I've already seen this post, but he doesn't actually cast the instance so it's not an exact duplicate of this post.

Comment: @neogenesis From the above post you are getting object of the .class file, cannot you try to cast it for desired object. Donot expect the everythign will be provided, then there will not be your efforts. :)

Comment: @melpomene I forgot to mention that the class file was generated during runtime, this is why I can't just use `new ObjectFoo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use third-party libraries, packages as .jar files, you will always compile and run against .class files. The .jar archives contain .class files, not .java ones.

So, the code above is correct, if the ObjectFoo class doesn't belong to a package. Otherwise, you will have to put the full package like path to the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried deleting the ObjectFoo.java file and I get a compilation error (ObjectFoo cannot be resolved to a type). I placed the Object.class file in the default package.

Comment: If you have ObjectFoo.java then don't delete it.

Comment: this is for testing purpose. I'm not supposed to have access to the java source files.

Comment: @neogenesis Just put the directory that contains `ObjectFoo.class` in the classpath. You don't need the source file to be able to use class `ObjectFoo`.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks, it worked. But I had to move the .class in a "lib" folder added to the build path. When it was in the "src" folder, it doesn't worked, I don't know why.

Comment: The src dir contains .java source files.

Answer (score 2):

To use a Java class, you do not need the source file. You only need the compiled class file, and you need to make sure that the Java compiler can find the class file at the right place.

Make sure that the directory that contains the file `ObjectFoo.class` is in the classpath when you compile and run your own code. You can do that by using the `-cp` option of the `javac` and `java` commands:

```
javac -cp C:\SomeDirectory;. MyProgram.java
java -cp C:\SomeDirectory;. MyProgram.java
```

where `C:\SomeDirectory` is the directory that contains `ObjectFoo.class`.

Note: There is also no reason to use reflection, with `Class.forName(...)` etc. to create a new instance of `ObjectFoo`. Just use the `new` operator instead; then you also don't need to cast.

```
ObjectFoo object = new ObjectFoo();
```